# Inconsistent image orientation correction in php for android 4.1.2

Tags: php, android, orientation, exif

When trying to fix the image orientation in php after uploading the image from android using the popular code:

http://snipplr.com/view/76539/:

```js
function image_fix_orientation($path){
 $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
 $exif = exif_read_data($path);
 
 if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
  switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
   case 3:
    $image = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
    break;
   case 6:
    $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
    break;
   case 8:
    $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
    break;
  }
  imagejpeg($image, $path);
 }
}
```

And it works for `android 2`.

We have inconsistent behaviour for `android 4.1.2.`
This code would not correct images taken by `android 4.1.2.`.

But this code does:

```js
   

 function image_fix_orientation($path){
     $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
     //$exif = exif_read_data($path);
     
     //if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
     // switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
     //  case 3:
     //   $image = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
     //   break;
     //  case 6:
     //   $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
     //   break;
     //  case 8:
     //   $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
     //   break;
     // }
      imagejpeg($image, $path);
     }
    }
```

For this version it seems that no `imagerotate()` is nessesary.. just `createimagefromjpeg()` > `imagejpeg()`.

Is there a solution? Or should I change the code only for this version??? Do you know why is this happening?

Please help,
Doron

Comment: Let's define "we have inconsistent behaviour for android 4.1.2." how it relates with php code o.o more info are needed

Comment: Hi I have edited the actual code we used. the inconsistency is for the android 4.1.2, where the orientation correction doesn't really fix the image. the image orientation would still be wrong, after running this function on it.

Comment: Did it happen to someone else? Do you know why is this happening?